# Minimum distance between pair of points in DBSCAN

Tags: clustering, anomaly-detection, dbscan

I have just used DBSCAN to detect the outliers. If $\epsilon$ is the radius as the given parameter, then a point is outlier means it's distance with all points greater than $\epsilon$, But I have just checked that each points has pair distance  less than $\epsilon$. So none of the data should be outliers. But DBSCAN has returned some outliers. Is it theoretically ok! Or I'm making bad mistake.
Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

If DBSCAN says a point is an outlier, it does *not* mean that it's distance with all points greater than ϵ.   DBSCAN has two parameters,  ϵ and n.  If a point is an outlier,  then it will have fewer than n points within a radius of ϵ (although that is not sufficient to guarantee that the point is an outlier).  It would be unusual to set n at 1 (in the R library, the default value of n is 5).